Replacing light/vent/heat combo with light/vent combo in bathroom wiring is weird
We’ve unhooked the heater portion of the fixture at the fixture. We now need to convert the switch from three down to two. The wiring is from the 80’s and strange. Any help appreciated. Will attach images.

The images will help.  Did each option(light/fan/heat) have its own switch(three switches)?  If wanted to, could leave the heater switch there, but not connected.  The next buyer of the home will pull their hair out wondering what it is for.

Edit your question and use the sun/mountain icon to add pics.
